# VB.NET Application can't be installed - BouncyCastle.Crypto has to be installed in GAC

Tags: vb.net, gac

I'm kind of unexperienced in programming. I built a small software, that enables the user to store data, that are manually entered in my software, into a MySQL database. So far so good - during debugging and after release and installation on my computer it works just fine.

But as soon as it is installed on another computer, it can't be installed due to an error that says (translated from german):

The application can't be installed and startet. The application requires, that the Assembly BouncyCastle.Crypto Version 1.8.3.0 has to be installed in the global Assemblycache (GAC) first. Please contact the system administrator.

I have just no idea, what the problem is. As I said, on my computer it works perfectly fine. I did some research, but I wasn't able to find sources that I understand to solve the problem.

Here are some details:
Language: VB.NET

Environment: Visual Studio 2013

Framework: .NET Framework 4.5.2

I would really appreciate, if you could help me with this problem!

Thanks in advance!
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with MySql.Data v8.0.27 for me.  Try installing v8.0.25 which seems to not require these extra unneeded bouncycastle .dll's